# what is the difference between "chase" and "chase down"?

Tags: meaning, difference

what is the difference between "chase" and "chase down"??

chasing a daydream

chasing down a daydream

I think there is no difference in meaning.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to wait a day or two before marking and answer as accepted. Other people may have good answers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Chase down** is a *phrasal verb* meaning:

> 1. to follow and catch (someone or something):
>
>    Police chased down the robber in an alley.
> 2. to search for and find (someone or something):
>
>    I finally chased down that recipe I promised you.  I chased him down
>      at his old hangout.

Whereas, **Chase** is a *word* which could be used in different ways.

As a verb:

> 1. pursue in order to catch or catch up with: police chased the stolen car through the city
> 2. seek the company of(a member of the opposite sex) in an obvious way: he spends all his free time chasing girls

As a noun:

> 1. an act of pursuing someone or something: they captured the youths after a brief chase

In a nutshell, one is just a **word**, but together it becomes a **phrasal verb**.